# SQL BigQuery: Identifying customers to stopped buying the products

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table where I have **DISTINCT CustomerID and Date_Trunc(TIME,MONTH) shown below.** If a customer has many transactions within the same month, it's only represented in our table as **one record**.

| DATE | CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 111 |
| 2021-01-01 | 112 |
| 2021-02-01 | 111 |
| 2021-03-01 | 113 |
| 2021-03-01 | 115 |
| 2021-04-01 | 119 |

For a given month, M, I want to see Distinct CustomerID that bought from us at least once anytime between M-4 (four months before month M) and M-2(two months before month M) AND these customers did not buy in month M-1 (previous month).

Basically if we are looking at month 6, I want to all distinct customers that bought from us between month 2 and 4 **(looking back 3 months not including previous month)**  but then did not buy in the previous month (month 5).

[image]

The output I want is a table that is grouped by the DATE (month M) and shows the CustomerID of customers who used to buy (between M-4 and M-2) but stopped buying in the previous month (M-1).

| DATE (M) | CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 111 |
| 2021-01-01 | 114 |
| 2021-02-01 | 118 |
| 2021-02-01 | 113 |
| 2021-02-01 | 115 |
| 2021-03-01 | 119 |

Answer (score 0):

Your data already has only one row by month and customerid, so just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(yyyymm) over (partition by customerid order by yyyymm) as prev_yyyymm
      from t
     ) t
where prev_yyyymm >= date_add(yyyymm, interval -4 month) and
      prev_yyyymm <= date_add(yyyymm, interval -2 month);
```

Or more simply using `qualify`:

```
select t.*
from t
where 1=1
qualify lag(yyyymm) over (partition by customerid order by yyyymm) >= date_add(yyyymm, interval -4 month) and
        lag(yyyymm) over (partition by customerid order by yyyymm) <= date_add(yyyymm, interval -2 month);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but this method would be getting a list of users who, for month M, came back to buy from us. But what I'm looking for is more along the lines of... for month 6 => list of unique users in (month 2 + 3 + 4) combined and then from that I want to only get the ones that aren't present in month 5

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select date, customerid
from (
  select *, 
    array_agg(customerid) over(order by pos range between 4 preceding and 2 preceding) bought_in_3_months_before_prev,
    array_agg(customerid) over(order by pos range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) bought_in_prev,
  from (
    select *, date_diff(date, '2000-01-01', month) pos
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
) t, unnest(array(
  select distinct id
  from t.bought_in_3_months_before_prev id
  where not id in (select * from t.bought_in_prev)
)) customerid
```

> UPDATE:
> In case of really big volume of data in your table leading to memory / resources related issues - use below approach

```
select * from (
  select date_add(date, interval offset month) as date, customerid
  from `project.dataset.table`, unnest([2,3,4]) offset 
  except distinct 
  select date_add(date, interval 1 month) as date, customerid
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
where date <= (select max(date) from `project.dataset.table`)
```

Just in case if you are not fully comfortable with `except distinct` operator - you can use below version with more usual/traditional `union distinct` - both versions are pretty self-explanatory so it is more matter of preferences

```
select date, customerid from (
  select date_add(date, interval offset month) as date, customerid, true flag 
  from `project.dataset.table`, unnest([2,3,4]) offset 
  union distinct
  select date_add(date, interval 1 month) as date, customerid, false flag
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
where date <= (select max(date) from `project.dataset.table`)
group by date, customerid
having logical_and(flag)
```